# np: "Upstream branch not found; not pushing."

Tags: npm

Command `np` gives me `→ Upstream branch not found; not pushing.` and doesn't open the GitHub repo to draft a release. Why?

[image]

I'm using np v5.0.3 on bash v4.4.19(1)-release on Windows 8.1 without VS Code or any IDE running with the folder open. (I know that VS Code and np don't play nicely). [Here's my package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datetimesfromduration), and [here's my package repo](https://github.com/Crowbrammer/DatetimesFromDuration).

```sh
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Crowbrammer/DatetimesFromDuration.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Crowbrammer/DatetimesFromDuration.git (push)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some technicality in Git I'm not aware of, because `git push --set-upstream origin master` and then repeating the process fixed it.